# Is it possible to pass a template with a list of jobs to a jobList type param?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Currently in Azure pipelines, we can pass the list of jobs to be executed to a child template with a parameter of `jobList` type as shown in the doco.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#iterative-insertion

Is there a way I can encapsulate these jobs from pipeline.yml that are being passed to the `jobList` param inside another job template and pass that template to a `jobList` param. I tried to structure my pipeline as follows:

```
pipeline.yml
deployment-template.yml
post-deploy-tests-dev.yml
post-deploy-smoke-tests-prod.yml
```

I would like to dynamically insert different tests' jobs to the end of the `deployment template` depending on the environment. I tried the `jobList` type parameter in the `deployment-template.yml` as the following but it throws an error saying `mapping not expected`.

```
#post-deploy-tests-dev.yml
jobs:
    - job: Test1
      steps:
      - script: execute test1

#post-deploy-tests-smoke-tests-prod.yml
jobs:
    - job: Test2
      steps:
      - script: execute test2

#pipeline.yml
...
- template: deployment-template.yml
  parameters:
    environment: dev
    testsJobsList: 
      template: post-deploy-tests-dev.yml
- template: deployment-template.yml
  parameters:
    environment: prod
    testsJobsList: 
      template: post-deploy-smoke-tests-prod.yml

#deployment-template.yml
parameters:
  - name: testsJobsList
    type: jobList
    default: []
#All deployment jobs here
jobs:
...
...
#Tests as the end
  - ${{ parameters.testsJobsList }}
```

Is there a way to dynamically pass the `jobList` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it throws an error saying mapping not expected.

Test with the YAML sample, the cause of this issue: you are missing `-` before the template field in **pipeline.yml** file (`- template: post-deploy-tests-dev.yml` and `- template: post-deploy-smoke-tests-prod.yml`). In this position, template is equivalent to a job, and you need to add `-`.

Here is my Sample:

**pipeline.yml**

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

jobs:
- template: deployment-template.yml
  parameters:
    testsJobsList: 
      - template: post-deploy-tests-dev.yml

- template: deployment-template.yml
  parameters:
    testsJobsList: 
      - template: post-deploy-smoke-tests-prod.yml
```

**deployment-template.yml**

```
parameters:
- name: 'testsJobsList'
  type: jobList
  default: []

jobs:
- ${{ each job in parameters.testsJobsList }}: # Each job
  - ${{ each pair in job }}:          # Insert all properties other than "steps"
      ${{ if ne(pair.key, 'steps') }}:
        ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}
    steps:                            # Wrap the steps
    - ${{ job.steps }}                # Users steps
```

**post-deploy-tests-dev.yml**

```
jobs:
    - job: Test1
      steps:
      - script: echo test1
```

post-deploy-smoke-tests-prod.yml

```
jobs:
    - job: Test2
      steps:
      - script: echo test2
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kevin Lu-MSFT. I had used `template` as `jobs` instead of `job`. Changing the `template` references to `- template` fixed the formatting error.